# How to configure Android studio to run on custom jdk which shipped with other jetbrain ides?

Tags: android, android-studio

The reason I want to do this because when changing the jdk for `Android Studio` from `1.6` to `1.8` the font is unbearable to me it is too thin...

I have read it some where that because `1.6` use Apple Java with `Quartz` to render font and that's why `1.8` not rendering the same way as `1.6`.

However, all other jetbrain ides like `AppCode`, `Webstorm` etc. are shipped with their own custom jdk `1.8` and the font look exactly the same as `1.6`.

The reason I need to update this because seem like with the new `build tools` `24.0.0` I cannot use older jdk version to preview the layout file.

Is there a way to make `Android Studio` use same custom jdk with other jetbrains ides?

PS. I have try to copy the folder `jre` from `AppCode` and paste it in `Android Studio` but when I try to open it I see this error

`'tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath.Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE`

Although there are a lot of answer to that problem but I don't know this error is occur because doing it in a wrong way or not?

This is the java version that I used

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Android Studio 2.2 Preview, Android Studio ships with the same JDK that the JetBrains IDEs ship with. You don't need to configure anything; just update to the new version.

Comment: This really is a good news! Why don't they ship it in the first place.. lol